How to merge time intervals in Spark
I'm trying to extract continuous timeframes in a dataframe in spark.
My input dataframe looks like this:



ID
start_date
end_date




1
01/01/1993
31/12/2018


1
01/06/2015
31/12/2023


1
01/01/2024
31/12/2024


2
01/01/1993
31/12/2017


2
01/01/2018
31/12/2018


2
01/01/2020
31/12/2023



My output should be something like this:
For ID =1 all the time frame is continuous, so 1 line should be extracted with the global timeframe of the three lines.
For ID= 2 the 2019 year is missing so 2 lines should be extracted , the first line represents the two first lines as the timeframe is continuous and then the separated last line.



ID
start_date
end_date




1
01/01/1993
31/12/2024


2
01/01/1993
31/12/2018


2
01/01/2020
31/12/2023



Any ideas how I can do this in Spark ?

This is another solution without using any UDF and purely PySpark API. I believe it's a better one in terms of speed perspective:
df = df.withColumn(
    "next_start_date", func.lead("start_date").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("start_date"))
).withColumn(
    "flag", func.when(
        (func.col("end_date")>=func.date_sub(func.col("next_start_date"), 1))
        |(func.col("next_start_date").isNull()),
        func.lit(0)
    ).otherwise(
        func.lit(1)
    )
).withColumn(
    "group", func.sum("flag").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("start_date"))
).groupBy(
    "ID", "group"
).agg(
    func.min("start_date").alias("start_date"),
    func.max("end_date").alias("end_date")
).select(
    "ID", "start_date", "end_date"
).orderBy(
    "start_date"
)

The concept is to see if the end_date value of the record is continuous with the next record start_date. If Yes, put it into a same group and calculate the min start_date and max end_date.

One way is to just group by ID and apply a UDF on the grouped rows. Inside the UDF, sort the intervals by start time and iterate through it, while forming merged intervals. At any point, you basically check if the current interval can be merged with the merged interval that you continuously track. If it can't be merged, then append the last merged interval into the list of intervals and start with the current interval as the new merged interval to grow.
Like so

data = [
    (1, '01/01/1993', '31/12/2018'),
    (1, '01/06/2015', '31/12/2023'),
    (1, '01/01/2024', '31/12/2024'),
    (2, '01/01/1993', '31/12/2017'),
    (2, '01/01/2018', '31/12/2018'),
    (2, '01/01/2020', '31/12/2023')
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", StringType(), False),
    StructField("start_date", StringType(), False),
    StructField("end_date", StringType(), False)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.withColumn("start_date", to_date(col("start_date"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \
       .withColumn("end_date", to_date(col("end_date"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

def merge_intervals(intervals):
    if not intervals:
        return []

    intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    
    merged = []
    merged_start, merged_end = intervals[0]
    
    for start, end in intervals[1:]:
        if start <= merged_end + timedelta(days=1):
            merged_end = builtins.max(merged_end, end)
        else:
            merged.append((merged_start, merged_end))
            merged_start, merged_end = start, end
            
    merged.append((merged_start, merged_end))
    return merged

schema_udf = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("start_date", DateType(), False),
    StructField("end_date", DateType(), False)
]))

merge_intervals_udf = udf(merge_intervals, schema_udf)

result_df = (df
             .groupBy("ID")
             .agg(collect_list(struct("start_date", "end_date")).alias("intervals"))
             .withColumn("merged_intervals", merge_intervals_udf(col("intervals")))
             .select("ID", 
                     explode("merged_intervals").alias("interval"))
             .select("ID", 
                     col("interval.start_date").alias("start_date"), 
                     col("interval.end_date").alias("end_date"))
             .orderBy("ID", "start_date"))

result_df.show(truncate=False)



+---+----------+----------+
|ID |start_date|end_date  |
+---+----------+----------+
|1  |1993-01-01|2024-12-31|
|2  |1993-01-01|2018-12-31|
|2  |2020-01-01|2023-12-31|
+---+----------+----------+


This can be solved with LAG function.
Basic import and data setup
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Continuous Timeframes") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (1, '01/01/1993', '31/12/2018'),
    (1, '01/06/2015', '31/12/2023'),
    (1, '01/01/2024', '31/12/2024'),
    (2, '01/01/1993', '31/12/2017'),
    (2, '01/01/2018', '31/12/2018'),
    (2, '01/01/2020', '31/12/2023')
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'start_date', 'end_date'])

# Convert date strings to date type
df = df.withColumn("start_date", to_date(col("start_date"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \
       .withColumn("end_date", to_date(col("end_date"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

Main code
The LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_end_date is the key line to the solution that get the previous record end date for same ID
# Create a temporary view for SQL queries
df.createOrReplaceTempView("timeframes")

# SQL query to find continuous timeframes
result = spark.sql("""
    WITH ranked_timeframes AS (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_end_date
        FROM timeframes
    ),
    gaps AS (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            CASE 
                WHEN prev_end_date IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(start_date, prev_end_date) > 1 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS gap
        FROM ranked_timeframes
    ),
    grouped_timeframes AS (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            SUM(gap) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
        FROM gaps
    )
    SELECT 
        ID,
        MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
        MAX(end_date) AS end_date
    FROM grouped_timeframes
    GROUP BY ID, grp
    ORDER BY ID, start_date
""")

# Show the result
result.show()


Output:
+---+----------+----------+
| ID|start_date|  end_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|1993-01-01|2024-12-31|
|  2|1993-01-01|2018-12-31|
|  2|2020-01-01|2023-12-31|
+---+----------+----------+

